# Fresh Install of 16.10 results in CPU cores running less than normal

Tags: kernel, cpu

Installed 16.10 Server on IBM 3650 M3 with 2 quad core Xeon E5630 processors. Server normally runs 16 compute intensive apps driving each core to 100%. After install of 16.10, some cores (maybe 2 or 3) would run at 100% but others would fail to exceed 50% for any length of time. System avgs 100% busy everyday but after 16.10 install, it ran at about 50%. Top showed 51% busy and 49% idle with 16 jobs running. Fell back to 16.04 and all 16 jobs ran normally, driving each core to 100%. Suspect there might be a possible CPU firmware problem in the 4.8 kernel. Anyone else encountered this issue. BTW, 16.10 installed on other CPU models like E55xx and i5 series don't seem to have this problem. Anyone else encountered this issue?